# PHP Data on HTML Table - Expand HTML Table

Tags: php, html, mysql, css

I am wanting to grab data from the database and display it in an html table. My dilemma is that if there are more than x number of rows returned, I need to be able to extend the html table as seen in the image below. So, for example, if only 10 rows are returned, they are displayed in one straight table (as seen in the first example image). Whereas if say 20 were returned, it would push some of them over to the second "table" to the right (as seen the second example image). I am not sure how to accomplish this with php. If someone could assist me, I would much appreciate it.

[image: my invision]

Comment: You should try something before you ask for help

Answer (score 1):

I think the approach I would take is to fetch the rows from MySQL into two separate 2D arrays, rather than attempt to build both HTML `<table>` on the fly.

In the MySQL fetch loop, iterate over the columns of each row and when you exceed your number `$maxcols`, start appending to the other array instead.  Then when finished with the fetch loop, iterate over the two arrays separately to build your HTML tables.

There are a few ways to manage the nested loops. This is the first that comes to mind

```
// An array initialized for each table (will become 2D arrays)
$t1 = array();
$t2 = array();

// Max cols in the first table
$maxcols = 10;

// Your fetch loop (pseudocode since we don't know which API you use)
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    // New row in both table arrays
    $new_t1 = array();
    $new_t2 = array();

    // Loop over columns
    $idx = 0;
    foreach ($row as $col) {
      if ($idx < $maxcols) {
         // Index is less than maxcols, append to the first table's new row
         $new_t1[] = $col;
      }
      // >= maxcols, append to second table's new row
      else $new_t2[] = $col;

      // Increment the index
      $idx++;
    }
    // Each of the two `$new_t* arrays now comprises a complete table row
    // Append each new array as a row onto the correct table 2D array
    $t1[] = $new_t1;
    $t2[] = $new_t2;
}
```

Then loop over each of the arrays `$t1, $t2` to build your two tables.